# Error: cannot import name 'pi'

Tags: python, python-3.x

for some reason I'm getting an error when I try to import pi in my code. For example, I'll create a file in Text Wrangler with the following code:

```
from math import pi

print(pi * 2)
```

When I run the code in Terminal, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex.py", line 1, in <module>
    from math import pi
ImportError: cannot import name 'pi'
```

This just seems very weird to me, and through some research I've read a bit about circular dependencies but I don't think that's really relevant. Any help would be great!

Comment: You have file named `math.py` in same directory where `ex.py` is located.

Comment: Your code works here. Are you sure you don't have a file `math.py` which shadows the real library?

Comment: @Jake: If you're not sure if you are using the system `math` that everyone here thinks you're not using, could you include the output of `math.__file__`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works well on Python 3.4.3:

```
>>> from math import pi
>>> pi
3.141592653589793
```

Check whether you have another module named `math` by typing `pip freeze` in terminal, or check if you have a python file named math.py. If you do change its name.